# ¿Cómo funciona exactamente el Hacer/Mientras Que?

Tags: pseint

Bien, estoy aprendiendo a programar y el algoritmo consiste en que el usuario ingresa un valor frontera y se comienza a escribir la siguiente sucesión: 2,5,7,10,12,15,... Esta sucesión no puede superar el valor ingresado por el usuario. Pero como se puede observar hace dos iteraciones más y no entiendo el porqué, si ambas variables m y n llegan a tener el mismo valor.

[image: Código]

Comment: significa que repetirá lo que tengas en ese bloque mientras que M sea mayor igual que N

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Es importante mostrar el código en formato texto. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y reemplaza la imagen. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este algoritmo siempre va a hacer una iteración como mínimo porque comprueba después de las acciones del bloque repeat/mientras.
Además también puede escribir un valor de N mayor que M por que comprueba si M>= N al final.

```
Por ejemplo si M es 0 tendrás 
M = 0
Paso     N    Escribe
---------------------
1        2      2         //N ya supera a M pero lo escribe.
         5      5         
   0 >= 5 : NO            ¿M>=N?
FIN            

Por ejemplo si M es 9 tendrás 
M = 9  
Paso     N    Escribe
---------------------
1        2      2   
         5      5   
9 >= 5 : SI                  ¿M>=N?
2        7      7    
        10     10            //Supera a M      
 9 >= 10 : NO               ¿M>=N?
FIN              

Por ejemplo si M es 10 tendrás    
M = 10  
Paso     N    Escribe
---------------------
1        2      2    
         5      5    
10 >= 5 : SI                 ¿M>=N?    
2        7      7    
        10     10            //Igual a M     
10 >= 10 : si                ¿M>=N?    
3        12     12
         15     15 
10 >= 15: NO              
FIN
```

Este es el funcionamiento del algoritmo tal como está escrito. Y puedes ver como al N se pasa del valor de M por poner la condición al final y por que escribe N sin comprobar si debe hacerlo (dentro del bucle).
Una solución es cambiar el tipo de bucle por un **Hacer si se cumple** y comprobar antes de escribir N (o antes de incrementarlo).

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que se detenga exactamente en el valor frontera del usuario. Entonces deberias proponer la condicion como m>n y no m>=n.

Pues en tu codigo, el bucle se ejecuta tambien si la condicion es igual al valor final ( es decir 25 >=25) y va a comenzar una vez mas, causandote esas dos iteraciones no deseadas. Para resolver aquello, proponle el limite solo con el menor(>) y no con el menor_igual(>=).

Te coloco la estructura del codigo con ese arreglo. Apreciaria tu retroalimentacion respecto a que tan eficientemente comprendi tu problematica. Saludos!

```
Algoritmo stack1_fix
    Escribir "SEGUNDO PROBLEMA"
    n= 0
    Leer m
    
    Repetir
        n= n+2
        Escribir n
        n= n+3
        Escribir n
    Mientras Que m>n
    // en el ejemplo que proporcionaste, m = 25 ; con este arreglo, se detendra en 25 y todo valor frontera que el usuario ingrese
FinAlgoritmo
```